# Microsoft.Bcl.Build Error

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms, nuget

Currently I'm developing Xamarin.Forms App,
facing the issue of Microsoft.Bcl.Build Error,
But I saw at Xamarin forums still does not solve,
is that any solutions for this?

[image]

Comment: You've added the Microsoft.Bcl nuget package to the platform-specific projects, and that did not help?

Comment: I've had this issue before. You need to make sure you are naming your packages in small caps and make sure that you don't have any project before that uses the same name or package name.

Answer (score 1):

According to the warning message and the default Blank App(Xamarin.Forms Portable) project I created, this issue caused by the NuGet packages that you installed in your PetApp.csproj which dependencies Microsoft.Bcl.Build package are not installed in other projects that reference the PetApp project.

Please install the same packages in other projects that reference PetApp project. You could check the Project column in Error List window to confirm which project need to install these packages.

Please note: Installed the packages that include Microsoft.Bcl.Build dependencies, not only install the Microsoft.Bcl.Build package.
[image]

In addition, the Microsoft.Bcl.Build project is not compatible with .Droid project that in Xamarin.Forms project. So if there has a .Droid project in your Xamarin.Forms project, this warning message could not be removed unless you remove the .Droid project.